# a legal term to refer to "public right prosecution"

Tags: word-choice, terminology

is there a legal term to refer to "public right prosecution" which is a fine charged by the public prosecution in the case a complain was filed against a drawer of a bounced cheque.. the drawer is subject to criminal charges and a fine for the public right prosecution? thank you

Comment: Do you mean: a law that prosecutes financial fraud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The law varies based on the legal jurisdiction.  In the US, there may be a financial penalty which is called just a "fine".  For example, in California:

> Most criminal violations of Penal Code 476a PC California's bad checks law are what we call "wobblers."  A California wobbler is a charge that the prosecution may file as either a misdemeanor or a felony, depending on
>
> - the facts of the case, and
> - your criminal history.
>
> If you are convicted of the California misdemeanor charge, you face up to one year in a county jail and a maximum **$1,000 fine**. If you are convicted of the
>   California felony charge, you face 16 months or two or three years in the California state prison and a maximum **$10,000 fine.**

If you are talking about a different jurisdiction, then it probably depends on the specific language of the local law.

The office of the "public right prosecution" may not exist in the United States.  Fines are paid to some level of government (the city, the county, the state, or the federal government) but usually through an *agency* of some kind (like the county court or the Internal Revenue Service) and not to a specific person.

Comment: I doubt whether writing bad checks is a  misdemeanor....

Comment: @Lambie apparently it is in California if the total value of the checks is less than $950, and the person has not previously been convicted of three or more forgery-related infractions.   [source 1](https://www.shouselaw.com/bad-checks-laws.html#3.1) and [source 2](http://leginfo.legislature.ca.gov/faces/codes_displaySection.xhtml?sectionNum=476a.&lawCode=PEN) .  I actually don't see anything about felony vs. misdemeanor in the text of the law, so I'm going to have to accept the shouselaw site on faith, as other sites corroborate.

Comment: thank you Andrew and Lambie.. what Andrew wrote is very close.. however, the term I am looking for is related to the name of the "fine" or the financial penalty charged by the Prosecution Attorney office and not to the felony.. it is charged as a compensation for disturbing the public..and it varies as Andrew said..maybe in the US there is no such fine and it is only in a couple of Arab countries ..if you are not familiar with it..

Comment: @Haneen  That particular office probably doesn't exist here.

Comment: @Haneen It may exist if I could grasp what you mean by right of public prosecution. Please note: prosecuting attorney general. There are fines given in common law countries for "disturbing the peace". But that's for bad behavior in public: too much noise or drunkenness.

Comment: @Haneen - I don't think we have a special name for it.  It's just called "a fine".  Also, in the US, the fine is technically imposed by the judicial branch, not by the prosecutor's office.